Significance of tangent indicatrix
I'm reading a proof of the Four Vertex Theorem, and the proof introduces the notion of a tangent indicatrix. 
The precise text is as shown above. Can someone explain the intuition behind the tangent indicatrix, as well as its significant in studying a curve? Is it based on the parameterization formula of this tangent indicatrix, we can calculate how much the direction is changing instantaneously at any point along the curve?

If $\alpha$ is a unit-speed path, i.e., its velocity function $t$ has magnitude $1$ at each point, we may view $t(s)$ geometrically as an arrow, usually from $\alpha(s)$ to $\alpha(s) + t(s)$ (as on the left) or from the origin to $t(s)$ (as on the right).

Analytically, we may view $t$ as a mapping on the domain of $\alpha$ that takes values in the unit circle. That's the content of the highlighted remark.
(Strictly, the animation does not show $t$, but a reparametrization of $t$: The path $\alpha$ shown does not have unit speed, and it's a small pain to reparametrize numerically to get a unit-speed path.)
As for the geometric significance of the tangent indicatrix, the speed of the path $t$ as a point moving on the unit circle (i.e., the magnitude of the acceleration of $\alpha$) is equal to the plane curvature of $\alpha$. This is the content of the displayed equations below the highlighted remark.
Qualitatively, the faster $t$ changes, the more sharply $\alpha$ bends per unit length.
<>
Generally, if we have a vector-valued function $V$ (such as the velocity or acceleration of a plane path, or a field of normal vectors to a surface), we can normalize, replacing $V(p)$ by $U(p) := V(p)/|V(p)|$ at each point $p$ where $V(p) \neq 0$. The unit vector $U(p)$ may be viewed as a point of a unit sphere (e.g., the unit circle if $V$ takes values in the Cartesian plane), and the collection of values may be viewed as a mapping $U$ to the unit sphere.
In the study of surfaces, a Gauss map is a choice of unit normal field. As with the tangent indicatrix, the derivative of geometrically-defined a sphere-valued mapping encodes geometric information about how a curve or surface is curved.

Just like a natural parametrisation is a nice (but not always really convenient) way to parametrise a curve, indicatrix is just a tool that happens to possess some nice properties, that is,  its derivative in natural parametrisation is directly related to the curvature of the curve.
Notice how it's just the trajectory of velocity on a unit sphere.
